# How do I do the key strokes `C-M-c` in spacemacs?

Tags: key-bindings, spacemacs, ediff, keystrokes

I'm using spacemacs but trying to use `ediff-regions-linewise` to compare a couple regions of text. In order to confirm the selection, I need to do `C-M-c`.

This is probably a silly question, but how do I actually do `C-M-c`? I assume `M` is meta, but when I hold control and escape I get a `<c-escape>` is undefined. As a sanity check, holding control and the character `M` doesn't work either (selects the next line). Maybe this is a spacemacs issue because of remapped keybindings, but how do I do this in spacemacs?

Comment: `M` does stand for Meta, but this is usually the `Alt` key (at least on linux and in Windows). Does that work? (I don't use spacemacs, just regular emacs, so I don't know for sure, but that's what I'd try first.)

Comment: @MTS ah yeah you're right, Ctl + Alt + c works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're using `ESC` for Meta, you want to type it separately, as a prefix.

So on most keyboards you could use either:

- <kbd>ESC</kbd><kbd>Ctrl + c</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl + Alt + c</kbd>